# [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train], too many voltage retries, give up

Tags: boot, 14.04, asus, intel, ultrabook

Upon startup in Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus Ux32vd laptop, I get the following error:

```
"[drm:intel_dp_start_link_train], too many voltage retries, give up"
```

The computer boots fine otherwise, but I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Same laptop here with same error message. By the way @brandex, do you also have the occasional freezing of the screen like I do? [ctrl+alt+f1] then [ctrl+alt+f7] then [alt+tab] is the only thing that helps it -- maybe the gpu support is bogus?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/502761/second-monitor-no-longer-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-intel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have UX32VD laptop and found same problem. This realy comming up when switched to Nvidia.
Same freezes to me, so I do like ber4444 said <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Related bug seems to be fixed https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74931 already by patch.

Comment: After upgrading to 14.10, still the same bug. Filed a report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1387134, please comment there if you have a workaround.

Comment: Confirm same issue on Asus U36SD laptop with Nvidia 520 GT, not fixed yet in 14.10.

Comment: Also on UX32VD. Who is ber4444?

Comment: Happens to me all the time with graphics freeze, especially now with external monitor connected (via micro vga). Switching Ctrl+Alt+F* and back helps - for a while.

Comment: @donquixote Guy who posted this error on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1387134

Answer (score 0):

I see these occasionally on my Dell XPS 15 (L322X) it doesn't seem to hurt anything and I can't pinpoint a specific cause for it.

I doubt it's anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW.  I used to get `"drm:intel_* give up"` messages coinciding with actual and frequent screen blanking, i.e. monitor goes black for a few seconds, comes back, blanks again...

My solution was to replace my Display-port (DP) cable+adapter with a good quality DP cable with latching (about $10 online). A good DP cable locks into the socket and maintains good electric connections between the graphics chip and the monitor.

***Update:*** since replacing the cable a few months back, I haven't experienced any screen blanking nor any `drm:intel_*` errors.

The monitor cable replacement fix has proved to be a complete success.